# When does $\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|]\leq\mathbb{E}[X]$ hold for $X,Y\geq 0$ i.i.d.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $X,Y\geq 0$ be i.i.d. random variables with a continuous distribution with PDF $f$ and CDF $F$.

My question is: Under what conditions does the following inequality hold,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|] \leq \mathbb{E}[X].
\end{align}
If $X,Y\sim Exp(\lambda)$, then the above identity can easily be shown to hold with equality. Is it the case that if the distribution is more heavy-tailed than the exponential distribution, then the inequality does not hold? Formally, this would correspond to the hazard rate $f(x)/(1-F(x))$ being nondecreasing (for the exponential distribution the hazard rate is constant).

Answer (score 2):

One criteria that you can use is the following:
$$\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t) - 2\mathbb{P}(X > t)^2 dt \leq 0.$$

---

**Proof:** Note that for $a,b \geq 0$ we have $|a-b| = a + b - 2\min(a,b)$ and therefore
\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}|X-Y| &= \mathbb{E}[X + Y - 2\min(X,Y)] = 2\mathbb{E}[X] - 2\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)]
\end{align}
Next note that
\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}[X] &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t) dt \\
   \mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)] 
   &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y) > t) dt \\
   &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t \text{ and } Y > t) dt \\
   &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t)\mathbb{P}(Y > t) dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t)^2 dt \\
\end{align}
where we are using the tail form of expectation in both, and also the iid assumptions. Now from here we see that the inequality to prove is that
\begin{align}
   2 \mathbb{E}[X] - 2\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)] &\leq \mathbb{E}[X] \\
   \iff \mathbb{E}[X] - 2\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)] &\leq 0 \\
   \iff \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t) - 2\mathbb{P}(X > t)^2 dt &\leq 0
\end{align}
Doing some basic algebra, this is also equivalent to
$$
\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X > t)(1 - 2\mathbb{P}(X > t)) dt \leq 0
$$